# error: ambiguous overload for 'operator[]'

Tags: c++, string, operator-overloading

I have an error I don't understand.
The following snippet compiles

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
    std::string m_name;

public:

    explicit Foo(std::string const& name):m_name{name}{}

    Foo operator[](int index) const {std::cout<<"size_t const\n"; return Foo{m_name};}
    Foo operator[](std::string const& name) const { std::cout<<"str const\n"; return Foo{name}; }
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo{"Cool"};
        
    foo[0]; 
    foo[1]; 
    
    return 0;
}
```

but the following doesn't not compile for **index=0** when I overload the `operator[](std::string const&)`

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
    std::string m_name;

public:

    explicit Foo(std::string const& name):m_name{name}{}

    Foo operator[](int index) const {std::cout<<"size_t const\n"; return Foo{m_name};}
    Foo operator[](std::string const& name) const { std::cout<<"str const\n"; return Foo{name}; }
    Foo operator[](std::string const& name) { std::cout<<"str non const\n";  return Foo{name}; } //doesn't compile with
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo{"Cool"};
        
    foo[0]; //doesn't compile
    foo[1]; //compile
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

and in this case I have the following compile-error:

> ```
> main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
> main.cpp:25:8: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'Foo' and 'int')
>   25 |     foo[0]; //doesn't compile
> main.cpp:12:5: note: candidate: 'Foo Foo::operator[](int) const'
>   12 | Foo operator[](int index) const {std::cout<<"size_t const\n"; return Foo{m_name};}
> main.cpp:13:5: note: candidate: 'Foo Foo::operator[](const std::string&) const'
>   13 | Foo operator[](std::string const& name) const { std::cout<<"str const\n"; return Foo{name}; }
> main.cpp:14:5: note: candidate: 'Foo Foo::operator[](const std::string&)'
>   14 | Foo operator[](std::string const& name) { std::cout<<"str non const\n";  return Foo{name}; } //doesn't compile with
> ```

1. Why adding an overload with a `std::string` parameter make the `foo[0]` ambiguous ?
2. And why the problem is only with the index 0 ?

Comment: There is a defect in standard library - `::std::string` constructors are implicit and a a general language defect allowing `0` literal to be treated as a null pointer constant. So `0` can be implicitly converted into string . @MarekR add  -Wpedantic to enforce standard conformance

Comment: Problem is caused by fact that `0` is a special value, which can be converted to any pointer. So it can be treated as `const char*` which is implicitly convertible to std::string. Using `+0` will trick compiler to assume type is `int` (MSVC tdo not respect that): https://godbolt.org/z/PW3Eoj57e

Comment: But why overloading operator[](std::string const&) with a non-const member triggers the compile error ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **problem** is that the constructor `std::string::string(const char*)` is **not explicit**(and `0` is a *null pointer constant*) which means that  the both the overloads `Foo::Foo operator[](int) const` and `Foo::Foo operator[](const std::string&)` are viable but have the same rank. This in turn means that the call is ambiguous since neither of them is better than the other.

In particular, `Foo::Foo operator[](int) const` requires conversion for its first implicit parameter but no conversion for its second `int` parameter. On the other hand, `Foo::Foo operator[](const std::string&)` requires no conversion for its first implicit parameter but requires an **implicit conversion** from `0` to `std::string` using the constructor `std::string::string(const char*)`. And as neither of these overloads is better than the other, the call is ambiguous.

---

Note that this problem **doesn't** occur between the overloads `Foo::Foo operator[](int) const` and `Foo::Foo operator[](const std::string&) const` because in this case the former is a better match than the latter as it doesn't require any conversion for its second `int` argument and both of these overloads requires a conversion for their first implicit parameter.

---

Thus one simple(straightforward) fix is to add a non-const overload `Foo::Foo operator[](int index)`.

Comment: @leosch Yes, that was a typo. Fixed now.